# Getting URL from route collection

Tags: model-view-controller, collections, routes

I'm loading to route collection on MVC project multiple routes in this format:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", controller, action, seo.PageRefProductType, seo.PageRefProductId),
           url: seo.FriendlyUrl, 
           defaults: new { controller = controller, action = action, id=seo.PageRefProductId}
           );
```

When i'm accessing it with an APIController, I can use the Url.Route (derived from System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper) to get the friendly url in that route.

My question is, how can I access that URL when I don't have the method Url.Route, for example when I'm not in controller.

This is my app start on global.asax:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        //loading the routes here:
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
        LocalSiteManager.UpdateLatestReviewInManagedData();

        //cache - Here is where I want to use the routes
        LocalWorkFlow.StaticCache.LoadStaticCache(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
```

Here is what I want in LoadStaticCache:

```
public static void LoadStaticCache(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //get the URL of specific route by its' name
    string myUrl = routes["myUrlName"].Url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did for now is adding each route name and url to a Dictonary where my key is the route name, and value is the url, then I can access it from anywhere I want...